# Natively reformatting JSON objects to prepare them for a JS Graph

Tags: javascript, json

Current JSON I'm working with:

```
[
  {
    "price": 498,
    "source": "example",
    "timestamp": 1569700356
  },
  {
    "price": 499,
    "source": "example",
    "timestamp": 1569700357
  },
  {
    "price": 479,
    "source": "example2",
    "timestamp": 1569700358
  },
  {
    "price": 498,
    "source": "example2",
    "timestamp": 1569786756
  }
]
```

Expected Result:

```
     [{
          name: 'example',
          data: [
            [1569700356, 498],
            [1569700357, 499]
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'example2',
          data: [
            [1569700358, 479],
            [1569786756, 498]
          ]
        }
      ]
```

**Above-explained:** The above-expected result will be the native JSON input I need to plot the price data correctly. Source `example` and `example2` become grouped with `[timestamp, price]` being grouped in a list under the sources.

**My requirements / my current approach:** I am wanting an elegant solution for this, I've experimented with data maps and trying to group by distinct... I don't want to have to result in doing lots of for loops & if statements if possible.

Comment: Where is the expected attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const array = [
  {
    "price": 498,
    "source": "example",
    "timestamp": 1569700356
  },
  {
    "price": 499,
    "source": "example",
    "timestamp": 1569700357
  },
  {
    "price": 479,
    "source": "example2",
    "timestamp": 1569700358
  },
  {
    "price": 498,
    "source": "example2",
    "timestamp": 1569786756
  }
];

const res = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (acc[curr.source]) {
    acc[curr.source].data.push([curr.timestamp, curr.price]);
  } else {
    acc[curr.source] = {
      name: curr.source,
      data: [[curr.timestamp, curr.price]]
    };
  }
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(res));
```

Comment: This seems to handle this much better than .map, name was undefined fixed with `name: curr.name` -> `name: curr.source` . However, the result is close, but not matching expected. I think this is enough of a direction I can finish this now. I'll update if/when I get the final expected result. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can have a utility function to process your data. It uses a map to group items with same source.

```
function processData(data) {
  const unique = new Map();

  data.forEach(item => {
    const { source, price, timestamp } = item;
    if (unique.has(source)) {
      unique.get(source).data.push([price, timestamp]);
    } else {
      unique.set(source, { name: source, data: [[price, timestamp]]});
    }
  });

  return [...unique.values()];
}
```

Comment: Excellent, I swapped around `[[price, timestamp]]` to `[[timestamp, price]]` and it's matching the expected output. Thanks Abito